# mysql | show tables with specified name

Tags: mysql, database

I have a tables in my database and would like to select specified tables by name:

```
abc_dshop_cats
abc_eshop_cats
abc_shop_cats
abc_shop_mods
abc_shopp_cats
```

How can I get these tables: **abc_shop_cats** and **abc_shop_mods** using the command below:

**SHOW TABLES LIKE  '%*shop*%'**
And the command above is not working as return me all tables...

Thanks!

Comment: you need the description right? use `desc <table_name>`

Comment: Table name and next SHOW CREATE TABLE... command

Answer (score 2):

You could do like:

```
show tables like '%\_shop\_%'
```

This will get

```
abc_shop_cats
abc_shop_mods
```

but not

```
abc_dshop_cats
abc_eshop_cats
abc_shopp_cats
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table_name
from information_schema.tables
where table_name like '%shop%'
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a normal SQL WHERE statement to do it.

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_mydbname LIKE '%_shop_%'
```